# Beat methods to validate/test the output data with original data

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have built dataflows from customer input data in Asure data factory. We designed the Workflows which are built on Alteryx(another Etl tool) in Azure data factory .

Now testing the sample data is ok on both sides.

But how to validate the entire output of Alteryx and Azure to be matched/Validated. Is there any tool.

My output file format is CSV.

Is there any automation proceaa to validate all the rows of Alteryx outout and Azure Output so that i can be sure that i have built the right Dataflow logics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do verify the whole dataset through validate activity if thats what you want (that the dataset meets a certain criteria etc.):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-validation-activity

Dataset validation directly on Alteryx output is not supported, in which case you need to store the dataset somewhere that you just transformed in Alteryx like a blob store, then you can validate there. Validation activity usually supports file storage systems like datalake, (S)FTP, or a relational database.

You can also do this through dataflows but you need to store it somewhere, as ADF cannot store any files or data by itself. Once you have both datasets stored, you can for example do this through dataflows by self-joining the datasets, and creating hash values and comparing those values, there is a video like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GACpvMjOJgE

And here is another post similar to yours:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/856074/how-can-i-compare-source-data-(sql-server)-with-de

Later if you wanna do this going forward, you can use CDC.

Comment: No No. I just need to compare the 2 datasets .For example , if i have 100 rows in dataset1 and dataset2 has 100 rows , now all the 100 rows data of datset1 match with 100 rows of dataset 2 . Then i can say my transformations worled.

Comment: Sorry I understood that you wanted to validate the data of output of Alteryx. I updated the answer.

Comment: I think this works. But Can i have a shorter and simple method to compare the files. Because doing this for all my 150 workflows is an head ache

Comment: For me the easiest method to compare two relational datasets has always been SQL method. Maybe you can transfer them into database and try with SQL ?

Take two datasets into Azure SQL, and run select * from First_Table - select * from Second_Table, and you get differing rows,